# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again in volley

Tags: android, exception, android-volley

**Hi, I got this issue during communication happened to server using volley. I attached my code where the communication was happened with server.Please help me**

```
SharedPreferences ciuidpref = context.getSharedPreferences(Utility.CIUIDFILENAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences pref = SuiteApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(Utility.CLOUD_COMM_PREF, 0);
        if (!pref.getBoolean("rbDisable", false) && pref.getBoolean("rbTenMin", true)) {
            RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
            Cache cache;
            if (lockService.context != null) {
                cache = new DiskBasedCache(Service.context.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
            } else {
                cache = new DiskBasedCache(SuiteApplication.getAppContext().getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
            }
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
                mRequestQueue.start();

            String requestedUrl = Utility.mPINGSERVICE_URL + Utility.getCIUIDValue(context) + "&UniqueIdentifier=" + Utility.getUIDValue(context);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestedUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String responseFromServer) {

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError errorResponse) {

                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 2, 2));
        }
```

> After this request, If get response from server, again i try to communicate to server by using volley. That ack code was attached bellow,

```
private void sendAcknowledgePingService(final CommunicationInterface interfaceReference, final String initialPingResponse) {
        String requestedUrl = Utility.mPINGSERVICE_URL + Utility.getCIUIDValue(context) + "&UniqueIdentifier=" + Utility.getUIDValue(context) + Utility.mPING_ACK;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestedUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String responseFromServer) {


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError errorResponse) {

            }
        });
        ((SuiteApplication) SuiteApplication.getAppContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 2, 2));
    }
```

**Is there have any problem by using two request queue?**

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is , your received string size exceeds the limit of string max capacity to hold data,will you tell me the size of data that you are trying to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i receive only less size of response. Previously i forgot to attached my code with completely. please check once again

Comment: Can you just provide exact and complete trace. Also size of both responses

Comment: Also you don't need to use two request queues, 1 is sufficient in most of the case. So keep it simple.